# require is not define in Typescript + daisyui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, daisyui

So, i want to use typescript + react + daisyUI (tailwindCSS component), btw i am using vite

I am using `node` as `moduleResolution` in ts.config

but i get an error in tailwind config `require is not define`

[image][image]

i expect can use daisyUI + react typescript

Comment: Don't share code images

Answer (score 0):

It was happening to me with Flowbite, and I saw this answer from [Nuno Santos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77291236/19317479)
and it worked for me!

So, in your case, on your tailwind.config.js, you have this:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    './node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daysi-ui")],
}
```

And you have to change the syntax by importing the plugin, with a **import** statement, and then adding it like this:

```js
import DaisyUIPlugin from "daisyui/plugin";

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    './node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [DaisyUIPlugin],
}
```

let me know if it worked in your case!

Answer (score 0):

This work just fine.
import daisyui in tailwind.config.json then adding daisyui to plugins as following

```html
import daisyui from 'daisyui'
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [daisyui],
}
```

[https://daisyui.com/blog/install-daisyui-and-tailwindcss-in-nextjs/][1]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and this has solved my problem:

```
import daisyui from 'daisyui';

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [daisyui],
}
```