# import Flowbite js to react vite

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, flowbite

Hello I'm struggling with importing flowbite to react vite project. The problem is when I try to paste the line of code  plugins: [require('flowbite/plugin')] flowbite to tailwind.config.js file Im getting error "'require' is not defined" so I tried import, that dont work either. Does someone know how to fix that?

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

i tried import that dont work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Instead of using `[require('flowbite/plugin')]`, try to import the flowbitePlugin from 'flowbite/plugin'.

It should look like this:

```
import flowbitePlugin from "flowbite/plugin";

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "node_modules/flowbite-react/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [flowbitePlugin],
};
```

Let me know if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the official `Flowbite React` library, make sure to follow the installation steps provided here for `Vite`:

https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/guides/vite

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35455357)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was having this same exact issue, and I was just doing something simple... here's a video that solves it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7dkR4i-2I8

you have to install the npm package then add it to the dependency array in the the vite.config file.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35588234)